# How to overlay a popup message on top of an ionic navigation bar - ion-nav-bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to get a popup message to appear at the very top of the screen on top of the navigation bar (ion-nav-bar). I can only get it to appear immediately below.

The css for the div I am using for the message is:

```html
.notification-message {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  height: 60px;
  padding-top:10px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  color: white;
  background-color: #656565;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The html for the page the message div is in the file watchlist.html:

```html
<ion-view view-title="CUES - WATCH LIST">
  <ion-content>
    <div ng-hide="notificationMessage" class="notification-message">{{messageContents}}</div>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="watchlistitem in watchlist" href="#/app/trailer/{{watchlistitem.id}}">
        <div class="watchlist-movie-thumb">
          <img class="movie-thumb-image" src="{{watchlistitem.picture}}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-75 watchlist-title-genre-container">
          <div class="watchlist-movie-title">
            {{watchlistitem.title}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The ion-nav-bar is defined in the side menu file as follows:

```html
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="header-text"> <!-- removed bar-stable -->
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>

      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear" menu-toggle="left">
          <i class="icon header-bar-icon ion-navicon"></i>
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
      <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear"  ng-click="shareAnywhere()">
          <i class="icon header-bar-icon ion-ios-upload-outline"></i>
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 id="menu-heading">MENU</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/watchlist">
          WATCH LIST
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

The controller code that shows the message popup is:

```js
      $scope.messageContents = "You do not have any movies in your Watch List yet. Why not add some?";
      $scope.notificationMessage=false;
      $timeout(function () { $scope.notificationMessage = true; }, 3000);
```